# Udp Server Client java

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, client-server

I have written UDP server client program. The problem that i am facing is that when i am running server program, it is not waiting for client to connect. Whole code is executing after running till the end. And when i am running client side in between of execution of server side, client side is receiving data from its point of execution. Here is my server code-

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
     DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(4321);
        byte[] sendData;
        String sentence = null;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\Deepak.txt"));
        InetAddress IPAddress=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
     do{
              while((sentence = in.readLine()) != null)
              {
              Thread.sleep(3000);
              System.out.println(sentence);
              sendData = sentence.getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket =new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,IPAddress,9876);
              serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
             }
           }while(true);
  }
```

Here is my client side code-

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    String sentence ;
    while(true) 
           {                 
             DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
             receivePacket.getLength();
             System.out.println(receivePacket.getLength());
             clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
             sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());                  
           }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is connectionless, so there is no such thing as a connection in it.
You can only send a packet (in a *fire and forget* way, `send` in java will send the data to the port specified in the `Datagram`) or receive packet on the port (`receive` in java will block until there is a packet received).

So you would need to implement your own connection on top of UDP if you want to have a server that only sends data if client "connects" to it.

So summing up:

- `send` won't wait for anything, it will just throw the datagram on the wire
- `receive` will wait for a datagram to arrive

Having the above information you would need to write your own protocol to keep the connection.

Comment: Could you please tell me how i can implement my own connection on top of UDP if I want to have a server that only sends data if client "connect " to it. I am new to socket programming.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to change the server to do the `receive`? It is the easiest way.

Comment: No. My specific application needs to be implemented server as sender and client as receiver.

Comment: OK, so your client would need to have 2 threads, one will be doing `receive` and the second one will `send` in a loop (until the `receive` receives a datagram). Server will do the opposite, it will wait for `receive`, and only after it gets the initial datagram it will start doing `send`.